# Passing props twice for a Higher Order Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a webpage and realized a common style shared by each component (same background, border, and title style). So I thought I should make an HOC which accepts the inner content of each component as well as a title, and returns an outer component which wraps this inner component and heading.
At first I ran into a lot of issues trying to get this to work, being new to React, but now it's finally working but I still don't understand how.

Here is my HOC

```
const BaseBlock = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return class BaseBlock extends Component {
    render () {
      return (
        <div className={styles['base-block']}>
          <div className={styles['container']}>
            <div className={styles['base-block-head']}>
              { this.props.title }
            </div>
            <div className={styles['base-block-body']}>
              <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
}

export default BaseBlock
```

This is the WrappedComponent:

```
const HighlightsBlock = (props) => {
  return <ListsComponent items={props.items} />
}

export default BaseBlock(HighlightsBlock)
```

And this is the ListsComponent

```
const ListsComponent = (props) => {
  if (props.items) {
    return (
      <ul className={styles['styled-list']}>
        {props.items.map((item, idx) => {
          return (
            <li key={idx} className={styles['styled-list-item']}>{item}</li>
          )
        })}
      </ul>
    )
  } else return (
    <h3>No highlights</h3>
  )
}

export default ListsComponent
```

And this is how I'm using the component in my app:

```
<HighlightsBlock items={this.getHighlights()} title='Highlights' />
```

Now, I can see the HighlightsBlock component receiving props twice (Once when I'm using it in my App with props, and once inside the HOC Baseblock as WrappedComponent ). If I remove props from either of these places it stops working. I don't understand how this is working.

Answer (score 0):

When you render `<HighlightsBlock items={this.getHighlights()} title='Highlights' />` you are actually rendering the component returned by HOC which in turn renders your actually `HighlightsBlock` component as `<WrappedComponent {...this.props} />`

You can think of HighlightsBlock component to be nested two level deep and hence you need to pass on the props to it, firstly as `{...this.props}` from within `HOC` and then receive it as props in functional component

Answer (score 0):

This is because of `this.getHighlights()` in this line,

```
<HighlightsBlock items={this.getHighlights()} title='Highlights' />
```

Every time you pass `props` to child component this function is getting executed.

To solve this issue, maintain a state value in your `parent` component and set that value in `getHighlights` function like,

```
getHighlights(){
 //you logic to get data
 this.setState({items:data.items}); //considering `data` is object which has `items`
}
```

Now you can pass items like,

```
<HighlightsBlock items={this.state.items} title='Highlights' />
```